# R: Only keeping the first observation of the month in dataset

Tags: r, date, filter, dayofmonth

I have the following kind of dataframe, with thousands of columns and rows. First column contains dates, and the following columns contain asset returns indexes corresponding to that date.

| DATE | Asset_1 | Asset_2 | Asset_3 | Asset_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 1000 | 300 | 2900 | **NA** |
| ..... |  |  |  |  |
| 2000-01-31 | 1100 | 350 | 2950 | **NA** |
| 2000-02-02 | 1200 | 330 | 2970 | 100 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 2000-02-28 | 1200 | 360 | 3000 | 200 |
| 2000-03-01 | 1200 | 370 | 3500 | 300 |

I want to make this into a monthly dataset by only keeping the first observation of the month.

I have come up with the following script:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
monthly <- daily %>% filter(day(DATE) == 1)
```

However, the problem with this is that it doesnt work for months where the first day of the month is not a trading date (aka it is missing from the daily dataset).

So when I run the command, those months where the first day of the month doesn't exist are excluded from my dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is always ordered, you could group by year\month, then keep (slice) the first record from each group. Like:

```
df<-data.frame(mydate=as.Date("2023-01-01")+1:45)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  group_by(ym=paste(year(mydate), month(mydate))) %>% 
  #group_by(year(mydate), month(mydate)) %>% 
  slice_head(n=1)
```

Comment: the data is indeed always ordered and this did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `slice_min`

```
library(dplyr) # version 1.1.0 or later
library(zoo)

daily %>% 
  mutate(ym = as.yearmon(DATE)) %>%
  slice_min(DATE, by = ym)
```